# Laravel scheduler throwing error on executing xml_decode()

Tags: php, laravel-5, xml-rpc

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I have this line under schedule() function in App\Console\Kernel.php.

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Controller@fetchXmlRpcResult')->everyMinute();
```

The function is sort of tedious but the jist of it: get the timestamp of the last record found in the database, create a new XML-RPC request asking for new records with start_date of the 'last found timestamp in the DB', decode the XML-RPC result and insert into the DB.

```
public static function fetchXmlRpcResult($user, $password, $account_id, $date)
    {
        $client = new Client('https://example.com/xmlapi/');
                $client->setSSLVerifyPeer(false);
                $client->setSSLVerifyHost(2);
                $client->setCredentials($user, $password, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);

                $parameters = [removed]
                $request = new Request('getAccountData', $parameters);

        $response = $client->send($request);

        // removing the 401 HTTP Unauthorized header
        $xml = (substr($response->raw_data, strpos($response->raw_data, "\r\n\r\n")+4));

        // removing the OK HTTP header
        $xml2 = (substr($xml, strpos($xml, "\r\n\r\n")+4));

        $accountCDRs = xmlrpc_decode($xml2);

        return $accountInfo;
    }
```

When I run `php artisan schedule:run` in the console, I'm prompted with this error:

```
Running scheduled command: App\Http\Controllers\Controller@fetchXmlRpcResult

XML-RPC: PhpXmlRpc\Helper\Http::parseResponseHeaders: HTTP error, got response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined function App\Helpers\xmlrpc_decode()
```

The controller uses the file in App\Helpers\XmlHandler.php and in that file I use the following classes:

```
use PhpXmlRpc\Value;
use PhpXmlRpc\Request;
use PhpXmlRpc\Client;
```

Could the HTTP response be throwing it out? I tried executing the same function via the browser (aka putting the function in the route.php under http://example.com/update) and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I just had to install php7.0-xmlrpc package (Ubuntu) and enable it on the PHP CLI's php.ini

Answer (score 1):

You should try upgrading to the very latest version of the phpxmlrpc library.
It has fixed a bug that prevented it to be correctly used for making calls that use basic/digest auth using curl.

You could then remove the lines where you try to do manually the removal of the http headers from the response and the extra parsing of the response, and just use `$response->value()`